# how to open and query .sqlite database read-only in flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, flutter-layout, sqflite

```
void openDb() async {
  Database _db;
  _db ??
      await openReadOnlyDatabase(
          'package:myAppName/databasesFolder/db_drill_pipe.sqlite');
  var list = await _db.query('table_name_1', columns: ['column_title_1]);
  print('$list');
}
```

I get this error:

```
Tried calling: query("table_name_1", columns: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList')
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      openDb (package:kbook/databases/db_helper.dart:50:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I have one database file with .sqlite extension, it has three tables. All I need is to open and query data from that file when the user triggers during runtime, I will never write or update the database, read only. I thought this would be more responsive than json but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps in some way, it's how I use it in my code:

```
Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _databaseConnection.setDatabase();
    return database;
  }

readData(table) async {
    var connection = await database;
    return await connection.query(table);
  }

read() async {
    return await _repository.readData('Table');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error has anything to do with sqflite. Indeed `_db` is null as it is not assigned to anything. I think instead of

```dart
 _db ?? await openReadOnlyDatabase...
```

you meant to do

```dart
 _db = await openReadOnlyDatabase....
```